# Serious problem with angular build on production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an app in angular 8 and suddenly, every build I generate new and deploy in production starts throwing a lot of errors.

These are my Angular related dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
```

These are my Angular related development dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.8"
```

My angular.json production config:

```
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/modules.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": { "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"] }
  }
}
```

And now a list of some of the errors:

```
TypeError
f.ngDoCheck is not a function. (In 'f.ngDoCheck()', 'f.ngDoCheck' is undefined)

./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js in checkAndUpdateNode at line 19344:19

    if ((def.flags & 65536 /* OnInit */) &&
        shouldCallLifecycleInitHook(view, 256 /* InitState_CallingOnInit */, def.nodeIndex)) {
        directive.ngOnInit();
    }
    if (def.flags & 262144 /* DoCheck */) {
        directive.ngDoCheck();
    }
    return changed;
```

```
Error
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (URL)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_mod...


webpack/bootstrap in __webpack_require__ at line 83:1

            l: false,
            exports: {}
        };
        // Execute the module function
        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

```
TypeError
this._delegate.applyChanges is not a function

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.pre-build-optimizer.js in ngDoCheck at line 3832:30

            }
            else {
                var view = _this._viewContainer.get(adjustedPreviousIndex);
                _this._viewContainer.move(view, currentIndex);
                var tuple = new RecordViewTuple(item, view);
                insertTuples.push(tuple);
```

Things I have tried to solve the problem:

- rm -rf package-lock.json and node_modules and npm i
- change "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, in tsconfig.json
- change angular.json optimization to false
- change angular.json buildOptimizer to false
- remove Angular Language Service VS_CODE extension and reinstall dependencies
- change angular devDependencies to this because i thought it was related to https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78

```
"devDependencies": { "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.803.20", "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20", "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.3.20", "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.3.20", },
```

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful, I'm desperate.

Comment: you have pretty old environment. Any chance you can generate a project with `ng new` (which is v12) and put your code into a new project? Desperate times lead to desperate measures

Comment: @Felix At the moment this is a measure that I don't consider yet, the project is very big and complex and it would take me a long time to check that everything works correctly. Probably before doing that I would try to do an update to angular 9 or angular 10 and see if the error persists.

Thank you very much for your answer